# How to concat php arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I want to concat all my array contained into one using php,

I have this array at the beginning :

```
{
  "errors": [
    [
      {
        "id": "login1",
        "error": "Invalid"
      },
      {
        "id": "login2",
        "error": "Invalid"
      },
      {
        "id": "login3",
        "error": "Invalid"
      }
    ],
    [],
    [
      {
        "id": "login10", 
        "error": "Invalid"
      },
      {
        "id": "login11", 
        "error": "Invalid"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

And I want to transform it like this :

```
{
  "errors": [
      {
        "id": "login1",
        "error": "Invalid"
      },
      {
        "id": "login2",
        "error": "Invalid"
      },
      {
        "id": "login3",
        "error": "Invalid"
      },
      {
        "id": "login10", 
        "error": "Invalid"
      },
      {
        "id": "login11", 
        "error": "Invalid"
      }
  ]
}
```

I try `array_push`, `array_merge`, `array_merge_recursive`
My errors array is populate with multiple arrays of logins, I want to have all in one array.
How can I do that ?

Comment: and... what went wrong with `array_merge_recursive`?

Comment: It erase the values of the first array

Comment: see my answer below, with an example link

Comment: @jszobody Based on what he's saying, I think he tried array merge functions on the parent array without traversing the sub arrays.

Comment: @BadHorsie yep, I agree. my answer should solve it then.

Comment: Definitely (+1). I was posting the same answer just after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, it appears your have JSON data, so you need to `json_decode` it.

Then it appears you need to remove the first level of hierarchy. Loop through the sub-arrays of `errors` and merge them all together.

Something like this perhaps:

```
$errors = [];
foreach($array['errors'] AS $subarray) {
    $errors = array_merge_recursive($errors, $subarray);
}
```

Working example: https://3v4l.org/JgqgO

You could also do this with something like `array_reduce` as well.

```
$errors = array_reduce($array['errors'], function($errors, $subarray) {
   return array_merge_recursive($errors, $subarray); 
}, []);
```

Comment: what do AS mean in the foreach loop please ? it means just put the current array as a sub one right ?